# Hadoop Remote Exception Error on minReplication of datanodes

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-emr, remoteexception

We are running our data processing Spark/Scala application on a 12 node EMR cluster. There are multiple stages during processing where we read and write the files to and from HDFS. Most of the time(99%) the data is being processed smoothly without any issues. But for some specific set of files pertaining some specific days ( like May5th or Apr 26th etc.) we are getting the following error:

```
2018-10-25 19:21:16,958 [task-result-getter-3] WARN  org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager:66 - Lost task 221.0 in stage 31.0 (TID 4910, ip-00-00-00-00.companyname.net, executor 4): org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /user/hadoop/working/fileType/CBO_33019.txt.2ea3ae69-8efd-eeba-4526-6511b0752fdb.fileType.xml.__temp could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 11 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.

at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:1735)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirWriteFileOp.chooseTargetForNewBlock(FSDirWriteFileOp.java:265)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:2561)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:829)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:510)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:447)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:989)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:847)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:790)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1836)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2486)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getRpcResponse(Client.java:1489)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1435)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1345)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:227)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:116)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy38.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:444)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor267.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:409)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:155)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeOnce(RetryInvocationHandler.java:95)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:346)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy39.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.locateFollowingBlock(DataStreamer.java:1838)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DataStreamer.java:1638)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.run(DataStreamer.java:704)
```

Can someone please help me decode this error? Most of the online help are falling into following 2 categories:

1. There are 0 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.
   or
2. There are 3 datanode(s) running and 3 node(s) are excluded in this operation.

But ours is a different scenario (see below) for which there is no such example anywhere in online forums.

```
There are 11 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.
```

What can we do to fix this error. Any help is much appreciated because this looks like a one of kind issue and might help many others out there. Thanks.